# .net core pass enum in View

Tags: c#, .net-core

I created a view, which creates a model. Model has enum field, like this:

```
public ProjectType ProjectType { get; set; }
public enum ProjectType : int
{
    type1= 1,
    type2 = 2,
    type3 = 3,
    other = 4
}
```

And in view, I display it like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProjectType, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProjectType,Model.ProjectType, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectType)
    </div>
</div>
```

When I,'m trying to reach this view, I get an error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'htmlAttributes' of
>   `'IHtmlHelper<Project>.DropDownListFor<TResult>(Expression<Func<Project,
>   TResult>>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, string, object)'`

I tried to fix this, by creating Html-helpers, but I need to use System.Web.Mvc, but I can' tadd it into .net core project
Is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

i think you cannot bind an enum directly to a dropdownlist.

try to add a helper construct like `List<SelectListItem>` on whick you can bind the dropdownlist.

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public ProjectViewModel()
    {
        ProjectTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public string SelectedProject { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ProjectTypes { get; set; }
}
```

you can use this in your view like:

```
@model ProjectViewModel

<select asp-for="SelectedProject" asp-items="@(Model.ProjectTypes)">
     <option>Please select one</option>
</select>
```

This should lead to this result:

[image: DropDownList]

Enum class stays the same

```
public enum ProjectType : int
{
    type1 = 1,
    type2 = 2,
    type3 = 3,
    other = 4
}
```